# Error when binding two instances Janusgraph on same graph

Tags: docker, gremlin, janusgraph, multi-instance-deployment

So I'm trying to deploy 2 instances of Janusgraph (v 0.3.1) to insert data in the same keyspace of ScyllaDb backend. To do that i deploy 2 janusgraph containers with docker. The first one is starting without errors and creates the keyspace in my ScyllaDb but the second one displays some errors.

So my Janusgraph containers works on a cluster while my backend works on another cluster. Actually, I tried with only one container to restart it when my keyspace Scylla is already created and I have the same problem. 
I also found a script clean.groovy that allowed to force shutdown the graph instances opened. But nothing works...

```java
5316 [main] INFO  org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend  - Initiated backend operations thread pool of size 8
5648 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer  - Graph [graph] configured at [/janusgraph-config/janusgraph.properties] could not be instantiated and will not be available in Gremlin Server.  GraphFactory message: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
java.lang.RuntimeException: GraphFactory could not instantiate this Graph implementation [class org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:82)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:70)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.lambda$new$0(DefaultGraphManager.java:57)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedEntrySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:671)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.DefaultGraphManager.<init>(DefaultGraphManager.java:55)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:80)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:120)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:84)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:343)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.util.GraphFactory.open(GraphFactory.java:78)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: A JanusGraph graph with the same instance id [0a0a01657-node11] is already open. Might required forced shutdown.
        at org.janusgraph.graphdb.database.StandardJanusGraph.<init>(StandardJanusGraph.java:165)
        at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:160)
        at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:131)
        at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:111)
        ... 18 more
5651 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized Gremlin thread pool.  Threads in pool named with pattern gremlin-*
5800 [main] INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Initialized GremlinExecutor and preparing GremlinScriptEngines instances.
7837 [gremlin-server-exec-1] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager  - Could not create GremlinScriptEngine for gremlin-groovy
java.lang.IllegalStateException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.lambda$createGremlinScriptEngine$16(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:464)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
        at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1382)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.createGremlinScriptEngine(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:450)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:219)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.lambda$getEngineByName$0(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:57)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:263)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:397)
        at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.lambda$createGremlinScriptEngine$16(DefaultGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:460)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:713)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:395)
        ... 26 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: graph for class: Script1
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:66)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:310)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:16)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.jsr223.GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.eval(GremlinGroovyScriptEngine.java:690)
        ... 27 more
7841 [main] WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Could not initialize gremlin-groovy GremlinScriptEngine as init script could not be evaluated
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportJoin(CompletableFuture.java:375)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.join(CompletableFuture.java:1934)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.lambda$new$4(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:141)
        at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeySet.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:559)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:136)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:120)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:84)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:343)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: gremlin-groovy is not an available GremlinScriptEngine
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.registerLookUpInfo(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:95)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.getEngineByName(CachedGremlinScriptEngineManager.java:58)
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.groovy.engine.GremlinExecutor.lambda$eval$0(GremlinExecutor.java:263)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I think all those errors are created by this :

```java
Caused by: org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphException: A JanusGraph graph with the same instance id [0a0a01657-node11] is already open. Might required forced shutdown.
```

And this is the script clean.groovy

```
graph = JanusGraphFactory.open('janusgraph.properties') 
mgmt = graph.openManagement() 
instances = mgmt.getOpenInstances()

instances.iterator().findAll {
  !it.contains('current')
}.each { 
  mgmt.forceCloseInstance(it)
}

mgmt.commit()
```

So did anybody solved this problem of graph ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally got answer ! So you can use ConfiguredGraphFactory but it failed for me. So for the first container i started it normally but the second one i added another configuration in the janusgraph.properties file :

```
graph.replace-instance-if-exists=true`
```

And it works perfectly !